# Execute commands in application deployed in Cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have deployed a Java Spring-MVC based application on CloudFoundry V2. My application needs to access another server by calling its webservices over https protocol. This needs that certificate should be trusted by jvm. 
So i need to execute command in jvm to install SSL certificate. But so far I don't see a way to get console of an application installed in CloudFoundry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to specify a custom start command for the application, and run the cert import command before the actual application start command.

Another option would be to extend the Java buildpack and either install the cert during the JVM setup (possibly by creating an additional "framework" component") or to have the buildpack set up the cert import in the start command automatically. See https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#configuration-and-extension for details on extending the buildpack.

Comment: I really like second approach to extend Java Buildpack. I am going to take a look on how to extend it in order to achieve this feature.